# Merge dataframes on keys, change value specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion, merge

Sorry if this question is already asked, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I have a large DataFrame with columns ['A', 'B', 'C'] where I want to fill `C` with another values of another smaller DataFrame based on keys `A` & `B`.

I don't want to do it once but recursively. I don't want extra columns `C`, I want to change the value within df1 `C`.

DF1 as follows

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | monkey | zoo | 0 |
| 1 | donkey | farm | 0 |
| 2 | dog | house | 0 |
| ... |  |  | 0 |
| 10000 | monkey | house | 0 |
| 10001 | donkey | zoo | 0 |

DF2 as follows

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | monkey | zoo | 1 |
| 2 | dog | house | 2 |
| 3 | donkey | zoo | 3 |

Wished outcome

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | monkey | zoo | 1 |
| 1 | donkey | farm | 0 |
| 2 | dog | house | 2 |
| ... |  |  | 0 |
| 10000 | monkey | house | 0 |
| 10001 | donkey | zoo | 3 |

Comment: Check out the merge function of pandas

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy.where in combination with pandas. You can chain numpy.where functions to add multiple criteria. It's not using a loop so the performance should be fine for a large set of records. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[1, 'monkey', 'zoo'], [2, 'donkey', 'house'], [3, 'dog', 'house']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['index','A','B'])
df['C'] = np.where((df['A']=='monkey') & (df['B'] == 'zoo'), 1, np.where((df['A'] == 'dog') & (df['B'] == 'house'), 2, 0))

print (df)
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe the monkey and zoo is a bad example from my part. But it are all unique values in the dataframe, so ((df['A']=='monkey') & (df['B'] == 'zoo'), 2,0) just happens once.

Comment: you can add more criteria, in this example I just accounted for one criterium

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand what it does, but it is not really what i am looking for. I have added some piece of the code, maybe that explains what i would like to do!

Comment: I adjusted my answer to show how you can chain the np.where()'s and add multiple criteria. I'm not sure what you mean with the piece of code you added.